# Validation stuck at first validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and my form validation works but keeps jumping to validate username on submit even when its validated. Heres my code

```
function validate_form(form)
{
   var complete=false;

    if(complete)
    {
        clear_all();
          complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);
    }

    if(complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkaddress(form.country.value);
    }

    if(complete)    
{
    clear_all();
    complete = checkaddress(form.country.value);
}

    if(complete)    
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkEmail(form.email.value);
    }

    if (complete)
    {
        clear_all();
        complete = checkphone(form.phone.value);
    }
}   

function clear_all()
{
    document.getElementById('usernamehint').style.visibility= 'hidden';
    /*.basicform.usernamehint.style.backgroundColor='white';*/

    document.getElementById("countrthint").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    /*document.basicform.countrthint.style.backgroundColor='white';*/

    document.getElementById("subhint").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    /*document.basicform.subject.style.backgroundColor='white';*/

    document.getElementById("phonehint").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    /*document.basicform.phone.style.backgroundColor='white';*/

    document.getElementById("emailhint").style.visibility= 'hidden';
    /*document.basicform.email.style.backgroundColor='white';*/
}

 heres the functions 

function checkUsernameForLength(whatYouTyped) 
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 2) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
        return true;
} 
else 
{
        fieldset.className = "";
        return false;
    }
}

function checkEmail(whatYouTyped) 
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(txt)) 
{
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    } 
else 
{
        fieldset.className = "";
    }
}

function checkaddress(whatYouTyped)
 {
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 3 && txt.length <10)
 {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    }
     else
 {
        fieldset.className = "";
    }
}

function checkphone(whatYouTyped) 
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
     if ( /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/.test(txt)) {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
    }
 else
 {
        fieldset.className = "FAILS";
    }
}

function addLoadEvent(func)
 {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') 
{
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() 
{
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function prepareInputsForHints() 
{
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
{
    inputs[i].onfocus = function () 
{
      this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
    }
    inputs[i].onblur = function () 
{
      this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(prepareInputsForHints);

 and heres my form 

       <form form method="post" action="mailto:s00103684@mail.itsligo.ie"  name="basicform" id="basicform" > 

                 <fieldset> 
                        <label for="username">Name:</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="username" onkeyup="checkUsernameForLength(this);" /> 
                       <span class="hint" id="usernamehint">This Field Must Not Be Left Blank !</span> 
                    </fieldset> 

                <fieldset> 
                     <label for="country">Country:</label> 
                  <input type="text" id="country" onkeyup="checkaddress(this);" /> 
                        <span class="hint" id="countryhint">This Field Must Not Be Left Blank !</span> 
                    </fieldset> 


               <fieldset> 
                <label for="Subject">Subject:</label> 
                  <input type="text" id="subject" onkeyup="checkaddress(this);" /> 
                        <span class="hint" id="subhint">Please Indicate What Your Interest Is !</span> 
                    </fieldset> 



              <fieldset> 
                <label for="Phone">Phone:</label> 
                 <input type="text" id="Phone" onkeyup="checkphone(this);" /> 
                        <span class="hint" id="phonehint">This Feld Must Be Numeric Values Only !</span> 
                    </fieldset> 

              <fieldset> 
                 <label for="email">Email Address:</label> 
               <input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="checkEmail(this);" /> 
                        <span class="hint" id="emailhint">You can enter your real address without worry - we don't spam!</span> 
                    </fieldset> 


 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input value="send" type="button" onclick="validate_form(this.form)"/>
                   <br /><br /> <br /><br />
                    </form>
```

Please point amateur coder in right direction Thanks

Comment: Wow, that's pretty long.  Is there any way you can simplify the code some?  Who knows, you may be able to find the problem that way....

Comment: put the code, where the problem occurs.. not your entire code

Comment: @tjameson ,@Tarun  i'm only learning javascript so i wish i could make it simple ,i dont know where the problem is .it sticks on validate name when i click button to submit , Please help i'm stuck here for 2 days :(

Comment: Too many problems with this code. `validate_form` function has totally wrong logic.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your browser? Use something like FireBug or Chrome's JavaScript console.  it should tell you the line that it's crashing on.

Comment: Where is your submit handler function? You've left out the most important one. Also, your `validate_form` is not returning anything in the end, how are you telling your submit handler if the form is valid or not then?

Comment: @majid, @tjameson, no errors in browser if i click submit highlights the name Msg"field can not be left blank" but when i fill it out it goes green for true/ok but does not fall into the next 1 country ,tbh i have no idea about submit handler function ,i took this as an extra topic in1st year in college an am regretting it now ,if you help me i will credit you in my script

Answer (score 0):

Please start with this ( http://jsfiddle.net/4aynr/4/ )

```
function validate_form(form)
{
   var complete=false;
   clear_all();
   complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username); // pass the FIELD here

    if(complete)
    {
        complete = checkaddress(form.country.value);
    }

    if(complete)    
    {
        complete = checkEmail(form.email.value);
    }

    if (complete)
    {
        complete = checkphone(form.phone.value);
    }
    if (!complete) alert('something went wrong')

    return complete;
}
```

and change

```
<form form method="post" action="mailto:s00103684@mail.itsligo.ie"  
name="basicform" id="basicform" >
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:s00103684@mail.itsligo.ie"  
name="basicform" id="basicform" 
onSubmit="return validate_form(this)">
```

and change

```
 <input value="send" type="button" onclick="validate_form(this.form)"/>
```

to

```
 <input value="send" type="submit" />
```

Comment: thank you for the reply ,                                onSubmit="return validate_form(this)"> do i leave this out ? i changed them but i still does not drop into validate country

Comment: No, mplungjan made a mistake there. That code belongs to the code block right before it.

Comment: heres is a live link to my code but i cant get the images up http://jsfiddle.net/MASP/xfaZF/1/

Comment: See update - you were not passing (this) in the onsubmit  http://jsfiddle.net/xfaZF/8/

Comment: @Martin - see new update. The main error was here:  `complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username); // pass the FIELD here`

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic.

Everyone has to start somewhere and it can be very frustrating when you're only just learning the ropes.

In answering this question, we need to look not only at your JavaScript, but at the HTML as well.

You don't have a submit input type; instead opting for a regular button. That wouldn't necessarily be a problem, except nowhere in your JavaScript are you actually submitting your form. That means every time someone clicks the "Send" button, it will fire the validate_form() function you've defined but do nothing further with it. Let's make a couple of changes:

Replace your button with a submit input:

```
<input value="send" type="submit" />
```

Next, add the following code to your form tag so that we define an action to take when the user tries to submit your form:

```
onsubmit="validate_form(this)"
```

So your whole form tag now looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:s00103684@mail.itsligo.ie"  name="basicform" id="basicform" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)">
```

Notice I removed an extra "form" from that element.

Ok, next we want to handle what happens when the form is ready to be validated.

```
function validate_form(form)
{
      // ...we can step through each item by name and validate its value.
      var username = checkUsernameForLength(form["username"].value);
      var email = checkaddress(form["country"].value);

      // ...and so on.
      return (username && email && {my other return values});
}
```

Each method you call (e.g. CheckUsernameForLength) should return either true or false, depending on whether the input is valid or not.

Our last return is probably a little inelegant, but is a verbose example of a way to aggregate our returned values and see if there are any "failed" values in there. If all your methods returned true, that last return will evaluate to true. Otherwise (obviously) it will return false.

The submission of the form will depend on whatever value is returned from your validate_form() function.

Comment: i changed my code to yours but used @kor validate function but it still gets stuck or wont fall into the next validation as in validate country ,if i click on the input i can enter validation and it all works but it wont fall through them when i click submit it only does name even when its validated it jumps back to it

Comment: heres is a live link to my code but i cant get the images up http://jsfiddle.net/MASP/xfaZF/1/

Comment: Please pass the form in the onsubmit, then there is no need to name it. Also you need to _return validate_form(this)_ and NOT submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, you are trying to access the username inside a condition, where the condition is **always** false. You set `complete=false` on start and right after that you try to see if that is true.

By the way, clear_all() may not have the behavior you want before the first validation. It will hide every input in the screen, so if there is anything else wrong, you won't be able to see that. I should go for hiding at the end (or at the beginning like @mplungjan stated, and always depending on what you need), maybe reusing your if(complete) structure:

```
function validate_form(form)
{
    clear_all();
    var complete = checkUsernameForLength(form.username.value);

    if(complete)
    {
        complete = checkaddress(form.country.value);
    }

    if(complete)    
    {
        complete = checkEmail(form.email.value);
    }

    if (complete)
    {
        complete = checkphone(form.phone.value);
    }
}
```

Also, and after stating the username validation works, you should return a boolean value in the other methods =)

**EDIT**: Also, checking the errors the others said is a high priority issue.

**EDIT2**: I turned to see a repeated condition. Now I deleted it. To keep using the if(complete) that way, you should also do these changes:

```
function checkaddress(whatYouTyped)
{
    var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
    var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
    if (txt.length > 3 && txt.length <10)
    {
        fieldset.className = "welldone";
        return true; // <-- this change
    }
     else
    {
        fieldset.className = "";
        return false; // <-- and this change
    }
}
```

Also, change the other methods to return true and false when you need.

Comment: i changed my validated form function to above but it still wont fall into next validation

Comment: see my Edit2 answer =) Did you also change that? (of course you should change all of the check functions)

Comment: yes i add return true; and return false to all my methods but it still does not jump to next validate country or there after even when name is valid it just stays on it

Comment: heres is a live link to my code but i cant get the images up http://jsfiddle.net/MASP/xfaZF/4/

Comment: @Martin Hm, something strange, it simply doesn't work to me. I edited your js and html files and indented the code. I added a couple of console.log() lines inside the checkUsernameForLength, just to check if it actually did something, but (at least in Fiddle) the method isn't even called. You can debug better JS using Chrome of Firefox consoles. Which browser are you using?  By the way, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xfaZF/7/)'s my code update

Comment: What is the point of validating if you do not react to the validation. See my update

Comment: @mplungjan I see, I just kept looking at the `<input value="send" type="button" onclick="validate_form(this.form)"/>` tag, trying to understand what would you do with an onclick="true" xD